# Can Internet connection be shared over Bluetooth without any app?

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, share, internet-connection

I've received an unverified information about a possibility to "share" a mobile Internet connection over Bluetooth 2.0 without any app.

According to the information, the method should use **16B-sized** packets that an *offline device* can send directly to the Internet over Bluetooth of *online device*. Something like **Bluetooth tethering with limited packet size**.

This method should be probably used by [FitBit](https://www.fitbit.com).

If it's true, where can I find more info about it? Libraries, documentation, code samples, anything. If not, are there other ways how to share connection over Bluetooth than Bluetooth tethering or creating an app which communicates with the offline device?

**EDIT:** The reason I don't want to use Bluetooth tethering is that needs to be allowed on the user (smartphone) side. This requires an additional action from user, thus this option is less user friendly. Sure, I could make an app to help the user with connection and tethering setup, but this would need him installing the app.

I just need to find out if this way is possible or if I should go with the tethering.

Comment: Hi Jakub, why you don't want to use bluetooth tethering since it is already a tested method for internet sharing. Let us know your requirement even more so that we can provide you more specific solution..

Comment: @aksonlyaks Hi, I have an alternative solution or two (tethering, app), I just need to know if this option is possible.

Comment: what I understand from your explaination is, you dont want to install anything on the online device or modify the online device. Am I right? If this is the case I guess it's not possible to achieve what you want. Because Bluetooth is not internally connected to internet stack to share net. When tethering is enabled, Tun/Tap interfaces help bluetooth to send over internet.

Comment: @aksonlyaks Thanks for your opinion. I also think this isn't possible, but the information comes from a man who seemed to be trustworthy. That's why I've tried to find more info.